# C# Process.Start() Continue On If File Not Found?

Tags: c#

I'm looking to use Process.Start() to launch an executable, but I want to continue program execution regardless of whether the executable succeeds or fails, or whether Process.Start() itself throws an exception.

I have this:

```
        myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        // You can start any process, HelloWorld is a do-nothing example.
        myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\HelloWorld.exe";
        myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        myProcess.Start();
```

I know you can add this into try catch

```
          try
        {
            myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            // You can start any process, HelloWorld is a do-nothing example.
            myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\HelloWorld.exe";
            myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            myProcess.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
```

Try catch version will not fail if file not found? How to go with other exception like InvalidOperationException Win32Exception ObjectDisposedException

The goal is just to continue with the code if this fail...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: why not just use `File.Exists("exeFilePath")`?

Comment: "Try catch version will not fail if file not found?" - It should do, if you're catching all exceptions...

Comment: @Sayse@JonSkeetso i should use the first option with File.Exists and I should be fine? My code will not throw expetion? I don't mind if te exe executed throws exception...

Comment: I'm not saying the exception won't happen, but its *very* unlikely

Comment: By "fail" in "try catch version will not fail" do you mean "enter the catch block" or "program crashes"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

catching exceptions should be reserved for the eventualities you expect to never happen but could possibly happen. instead you can try checking if the file exists first

```
var filePath = @"C:\HelloWorld.exe";
if(File.Exists(filePath))
{
     myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
     // You can start any process, HelloWorld is a do-nothing example.
     myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = filePath ;
     myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
     myProcess.Start();
}
```

**Edit**

If you want to be extra cautious, you could always use the try catch also but catch the specific exceptions.

```
try
{
//above code
}
catch(Win32Exception)
{
}
```

**Edit2**

```
var path = new Uri(
  Path.Combine((System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase)).LocalPath,
           "filename.exe"));
```

**Final edit**

When an exception is caught, your program enters the catch block to allow you to act accordingly, most programs tend to include some kind of error logging into this so this error/bug can be rectified if possible. It may be worth for the time being you just including a message to let the user know something unexpected happened

```
catch(Win32Exception)
{
MessageBox.Show(this, "There was a problem running the exe");
}
```

Comment: Some people recommend not doing that because a file can be deleted between the time you check to see if it exists and the time you actually read it.

Comment: And this scenario is for exceptions. But a check for File.Exists reduces the probability to hit an exception and it is always a good practice.

Comment: @JonathanAllen - Do you have any sources for this fact? I get the feeling threading is not in action here and the time before the check and usage here is very miniscule

Comment: @Sayse: Parallelism is always in action.  Even if you program isn't using threads, there are other processes running, and the filesystem is a shared resource.  There are also other things that can go wrong besides the file not existing (for example, insufficient permission to execute it, or missing DLLs).  So handling failure is necessary.

Comment: I'm afraid my code can fail and stuck in the middle I don't mind if the exe I open throws an error. So should I use Try Catch or without it?

Comment: @BenVoigt exactly I can't relay on simple function if it exists I want to handle the problem in my code if there is some kind of problem just skip... :)))

Comment: Mark, if you are to use a try/catch don't do it with `Exception` use the specific exception, I stand by my answer. @BenVoigt - Points taken on board, I was referring to this program in particular.

Comment: @Sayse If you don't mind can you add to your if code the exception I'm not sure how to use the a specific one? msdn shows this: InvalidOperationException, Win32Exception, ObjectDisposedException Also I was thinking And I think if file exists can be useful as well!!

Comment: It's probably `Win32Exception` you want to catch, see [`Process.Start` method documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8zac0ca.aspx)

Comment: Edited thanks (I've had a day of IOE'S and ready for bed so didn't check doc!)

Comment: @Sayse thanks! Looks good! can I know what "@" means here var filePath = @"C:\HelloWorld.exe";? I get the the exe location like this `var path = new Uri((System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase)).LocalPath + "\\filename.exe"`

Comment: It escapes the string so you don't need double slashes

Comment: @MarkVoidale - I've added a second edit of the better way to get the path

Comment: @Sayse thanks! ah sorry I confused you I think that `var path = new Uri((System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase)).LocalPath;` returns the executed main exe name so it should be like this no?                  `var path = new Uri((System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase)).LocalPath;
                        string startupPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(path);` and then `string startupPathexe2 = startuppath + "//filename.exe";` my second exe located in the same folder

Comment: My point was don't use string concatenation for building up a path, use `path.combine` instead so above would be `Path.Combine(startuppath, "filename.exe")` (there are other parameters available for this method with longer paths)

Comment: @Sayse thank you I learned path.combine just now! by your answer and also exception a lot of helpful information. just to make sure I understand this what happens when this try catch catches the execption? I can leave it empty and it will go on with the code? Or I can even write some code inside right?

Comment: Don't just swallow the exception, if you are to catch an exception make sure you do something with it. At the very least, show a message to the user telling them what just happened (in a friendly way)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34571/discussion-between-mark-voidale-and-sayse)